# Separating a date string into two

Tags: javascript

I have something like

```
var dateRange = "2014-02-01/2014-03-01";
```

I want to separate this string like

```
var first = "2014-02-01"

var second = "2014-03-01"
```

How to do this?

Comment: [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 4):

```
var splitString = dateRange.split('/');
var first = splitString [0]; //First.
var second = splitString [1]; //Second.
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
var dateRange = '2014-02-01/2014-03-01'.split('/');    
var first = dateRange[0];
var second = dateRange[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
var res = dateRange .split("/");

var first = res[0];
var second = res[1];
```